# Creating parallax effect with HTML background video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created a web page with parallax effect by using HTML5 video element and its working as expected in my local machine. But when I uploaded the files to my web hosting server and access the website the background video is not playing and it's totally not visible anywhere on the screen except a small portion of it appears below navbar when I scroll up fast enough from the bottom of the webpage.

HTML element:

```
<video loop autoplay>
 <source src="https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/howthatworks/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

CSS for my background video element:

```
video {
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
width: auto;
height: auto;
z-index: -100;
margin-top: 98px;
transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

Any ideas about this?

It's working perfectly when I run my website on the files that are stored on my local hard drive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please use the src of video link inside the source tag as given below.

```
<video loop autoplay>
  <source src="https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/howthatworks/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Here is the [codepen demo link](https://codepen.io/satheesh_design/pen/wrMBRX).

Comment: I did, but nothing happened.

Comment: Link to my hosted website is added

Comment: It is working perfectly on my device (Chrome Version 61.0.3163.91). Please specify the browser on which you are facing the issue!!!.

Comment: Is background video playing?

Comment: Thank you! it's working in my firefox but not in my chrome, maybe version problem.